# How to solve track disable error in agora when grab mic and mic drop?

Tags: agora.io

1. AgoraRTCError TRACK_IS_DISABLED: can not publish a disabled track:
2. displayCurrentSpeaker @ agora-client-video.js:288
   Uncaught (in promise) r {name: 'AgoraRTCException', code: 'TRACK_IS_DISABLED', message: 'AgoraRTCError TRACK_IS_DISABLED: can not publish a disabled track: track-cam-845cd018', data: undefined}
3. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getMediaStreamTrack')
   at attachStreamToBigCircle (agora-client-video.js:506)
   at async changeMicSpeaker

[enter image description here][1]

I attached error's screenshot . Please provide solution

[1]: https://i.stack**strong text**.imgur.com/BUH4X.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The track is disabled, usually because you have called [Track.setEnabled(false)](https://agoraio-community.github.io/AgoraWebSDK-NG/api/en/interfaces/ilocaltrack.html#setenabled) to disable the track.

Call [Track.setEnabled(true)](https://agoraio-community.github.io/AgoraWebSDK-NG/api/en/interfaces/ilocaltrack.html#setenabled) to enable the track and retry.

If you could share more code, we can debug it further.

See how you can change the device (mic and video) here: https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/test_switch_device_web_ng?platform=Web

I made a sample app doing the same: https://github.com/akshatvg/speakOut/blob/master/assets/js/goLive.js

Comment: By default, if `setEnabled` is not called at all there are no issues. However, by default video is enabled and this is not ideal for our use case.
Any workarounds for the same?